# Is it allowed to use window.postMessage() in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have finished coding my extension for Chrome and FireFox (WebExtensions). I have used window.postMessage() for communication between website script and the extension and everything works.

But now I am reading that there are methods by chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) like `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`to send messages. Will my extension be rejected if I use window.postMessage() so I have to recode everything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid way of communication - between a page and a content script.

In fact, if you look at the [Content Script documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication), it lists `postMessage` as a way of communication to the content script.

The method [described at the Messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) allows to cut out the content script as a middleman, and provides some degree authentication for messages (only the indended recipient will receive them), providing you configured [`"externally_connectable"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

But `"externally_connectable"` is not supported in Firefox yet, and I can't quickly find a bug that tracks its implementation.

Comment: Thanks that really took my fear of having to recode everything.

Comment: Is it possible to use `postMessage` between a page and the **background,js** script? If so, would the same-origin policy block any of such functionality? Please advise. Thank.